# Shiny not rendering html

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to create a link to an image on a table on a shiny app but shiny displays the HTML as raw text.The links are screenshots of over 100 sites. I want to add a link to each of the sites in a table. What am I missing? I have tired these approaches.

Example 1:

`ref <-  paste(l, '.png',sep = "")`
`link <- as.String(tags$a(href= ref,link_name))`

Example 2.

`links <- NULL`
`count <-  1`
`for(l in all_sites)`
`{`
    `link_name <-  l  ref <- paste(l, '.png',sep = "")`
`links[count] <- HTML('<a href=',ref,'id = "logo" target="_blank" class="btn 
                        btn-primary">',link_name,'</a>')`
`count <-  count + 1`
 `}`

Both examples produce the same result on the table.

`<a href= site.com.png id = "logo" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary"> site.com </a>`

Comment: It would be easier to understand with a full reproducible example... How do you render the link ? Why do you use `as.String` ?

Comment: because when i didn't this was the output   [[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "a"

[[3]]
[1] "a"

[[4]]
[1] "a"

[[5]]
[1] "a"

[[6]]
[1] "a"

Comment: i tried this as well  `links[count] <- HTML('<a href= ',ref,' id = "logo" target="_blank">',link_name,'</a>')`

Comment: You just have to do `tags$a(href=ref,link_name)` in the `ui`.

Comment: These links need to be displayed on one of the columns of a data table. I have screenshots of various sites, so i need to place the links to the screenshots next to each site.

Comment: How could we guess ? Please edit your post, ask a clear question and include a minimal reproducible example, with what you have done so far. This is the way to get help.

Answer (score 1):

All i needed to do was to set escape to false

`output$table<- renderDataTable({`  `my_df`  `},options =list(pageLength=10), escape = FALSE)`